# Event callback, using variable event-name. possible?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a custom class that looks like:

```
function myClass(){
  var thing;
  var thingtype;
}
```

I am  using a third-party library to create and manage 'A'-type 'things', and a second third-party library to create and manage 'B'-type things.

When my A or B type thing loads, I would like to execute a callback.

Suppose the first third-party library broadcasts an `onLoad` event when an A-type thing loads, and the second library broadcasts an `onReady` event when a B-type thing loads.

I could say:

```
if (thingtype=='A'){
  thing.onLoad(function(){alert ("my callback");})
}
if (thingtype=='B'){
  thing.onReady(function(){alert ("my callback");});
}
```

My question:
Is it possible to instead use a variable for the event-name, something like:

```
if (thingtype=='A'){
  myLoadEvent = 'onLoad';
}
if (thingtype=='B'){
  myLoadEvent = 'onReady';
}
thing.myLoadEvent(function(){alert ("my callback");});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onLoad` and `onReady` are normal properties of the `thing` object. To access any property using its string name, use `obj[x]` to look up that value:

```
thing[myLoadEvent](function(){alert ("my callback");});
```

---

Here's a simpler example to illustrate this concept:

```
var foo = {
    bar: function() { return 'baz'; }
};

console.log(foo.bar());                  // => 'baz'
console.log(foo['bar']());               // => 'baz'
console.log(foo.bar() === foo['bar']()); // => true
```